# Makefile with multiple directories and dependencies

Tags: makefile, g++

``I am pretty new to Makefile and I am trying to build a project.
This is the structure of my project:

```
-Project
|-generic
|  |-include
|  |-src
|-specific
|  |-include
|  |-src
|-Makefile
|-bin
```

Here generic contains mainly interface classes (virtual), and files in specific may depends on those.
I want to compile all sources and put their corresponding .o files in bin and also create a static library in bin.

**EDIT:**

```
CC=k1-g++
CPPFLAGS=-c -I$(GENERIC_INCLUDE_DIR) -I$(SPECIFIC_INCLUDE_DIR) -Os -std=gnu++11 -mos=nodeos 
CXXFLAGS=-c -I$(GENERIC_INCLUDE_DIR) -I$(SPECIFIC_INCLUDE_DIR) -Os -std=gnu++11 -mos=nodeos 
LFLAGS=-pthread -lnodeos  

GENERIC_INCLUDE_DIR=generic/include
SPECIFIC_INCLUDE_DIR=specific/include
GENERIC_SRC_DIR=generic/src
SPECIFIC_SRC_DIR=specific/src


LIB = libengine.a
BIN_DIR=bin

vpath %.cpp $(GENERIC_SRC_DIR) $(SPECIFIC_SRC_DIR)
SOURCES := $(wildcard $(GENERIC_SRC_DIR)/*.cpp $(SPECIFIC_SRC_DIR)/*.cpp)
#SOURCES := $(wildcard $(GENERIC_SRC_DIR)/*.cpp $(SPECIFIC_SRC_DIR)/*.cpp)
SOURCES := $(notdir $(SOURCES))
OBJECTS := $(patsubst %.cpp,$(BIN_DIR)/%.cpp.o,$(SOURCES))



all: $(OBJECTS) $(LIB)

$(LIB): $(OBJECTS)
    ar -cvq $(BIN_DIR)/$@ $^

#$(BIN_DIR)/%.cpp.o: $(GENERIC_SRC_DIR)/%.cpp
#   $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $< $(LFLAGS) -o $@

$(BIN_DIR)/%.cpp.o: %.cpp
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $< $(LFLAGS) -o $@




.PHONY: clean

clean:
    rm -f $(BIN_DIR)/*
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What happens when you try it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have `generic/src/foo.cpp` and `specific.src/bar.cpp`.

This:

```
$(BIN_DIR)/%.o: %.cpp
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $*.cpp -o $@
```

is pretty close to what you need (I've replaced `$(BIN_DIR)/$*.o` with the [automatic variable](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables) `$@`, which expands to the name of the target); the only problem is that it doesn't work. This rule tells Make it can build `obj/foo.o` from `foo.cpp`, but there is no `foo.cpp`. There's a `generic/src/foo.cpp`, but Make doesn't know that that's what you meant. We could write a rule like this:

```
$(BIN_DIR)/%.o: $(GENERIC_SRC_DIR)/%.cpp
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $*.cpp -o $@
```

But a tidier way is to use [the vpath directive](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Selective-Search):

```
vpath %.cpp $(GENERIC_SRC_DIR) $(SPECIFIC_SRC_DIR)

$(BIN_DIR)/%.o: %.cpp
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $*.cpp -o $@
```

This will do nicely for building any one object file, but you say you want to compile *"all sources".* That isn't always a good idea, but if that's what you want it isn't hard, we use [`wildcard`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Wildcard-Function) to obtain a list of all the sources, then convert that into a list of corresponding object files, then build them all:

```
SOURCES := $(wildcard $(GENERIC_SRC_DIR)/*.cpp $(SPECIFIC_SRC_DIR)/*.cpp)
SOURCES := $(notdir $(SOURCES))
OBJECTS := $(patsubst %.cpp,%.o, $(SOURCES))
# We could have done that all in one line, but this way is easier to read.

all: $(OBJECTS)
```

Now for the library:

```
vpath %.o $(BIN_DIR)

$(BIN_DIR)/$(LIB): $(OBJECTS)
    ar -cvq $@ $^
```

Further refinements are possible, but that should keep busy for a while.

Comment: Never mind I had a typo mistake in my flags. Works like magic. Thanks a lot

Comment: I found a new problem in the static library that I create. Some of the source files uses atomic of c++11 and when I try to use this library in a project I have such errors:
 src/engine/bin/libengine.a(Compound.cpp.o): In function `Job::restart()':
 (.text._ZN3Job7restartEv[_ZN3Job7restartEv]+0x30): undefined     reference to `__atomic_exchange_1'. You can look to my final Makefile in the edited post @Beta

Comment: @Mr.D: One question per question, please. Anyway, I'm not an expert in C++11, but it sounds as if you are trying to link object files that were compiled without the C++11 compiler flags, so I suggest you recompile those sources with those flags (perhaps with your new makefile).